# Uncaught TypeError: visitorIDs.push is not a function

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, error, jsom, people-picker

I am trying to build an array of the ID's of the users in a peoplePicker Field by using push.

So far I'm not having much luck as I'm getting this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: visitorIDs.push is not a function".

My code is below.

I appreciate any suggestions/pointers:

```
// Get information about all users.
            var users = peoplePickerVisitors.GetAllUserInfo();
            var userInfo = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                for (var userProperty in user) {
                    userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
                }
            }

            var userloginbase = users[0].Key;
            var userlogin = userloginbase.split("\\");

            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var newUser = context.get_web().ensureUser('xxxxxxx\\' + userlogin[1]);
            context.load(newUser);
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                },

                function (sender, args) {
                });
                // pause for a second to let the async ensure user complete.
                setTimeout(function() {

                    getAssignedToUserIdByEmail(users[0].EntityData.Email);


                    visitorIDs = ResolvedToUser.Id;
                    visitorIDs.push(ResolvedToUser.Id);

                }, 100);

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to declare an array at the start of your code/function like:

```
var visitorIDs = [];
```

Then in `setTimeout` function you can use it like below:

```
visitorIDs.push(ResolvedToUser.Id);
```

So, you need to remove below line from your code which is not necessary:

```
visitorIDs = ResolvedToUser.Id;
```

However I am not sure how you are getting `ResolvedToUser.Id` and your logic for getting all user's IDs from people picker is correct or not.

But above code will help you to resolve your `Uncaught TypeError`.